# Check whether a data frame comma separated column value is present in a list and based on that create final data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below data frame -

```
Id  value
A   1,2,3
B   3,4
C   5,6
```

I want to check if the "value" are present in below list -

```
B=[1,3]
```

and based on that, I want to create below resultant data frame -

```
Id  value_inscope   value_outofscope
A      1,3                 2
B      3                   4
C                        5,6
```

I have tried filtering or looping through the data frame. Can anyone please suggest a step forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an array from list B, and then use the `array_intersect` and `array_except` functions to find the intersection and difference of the two arrays respectively.

```
df = df.select(
    'id',
    F.array_join(
        F.array_intersect(F.split('value', ','), F.array(*[F.lit(e).cast('string') for e in B])),
        ','
    ).alias('value_inscope'),
    F.array_join(
        F.array_except(F.split('value', ','), F.array(*[F.lit(e).cast('string') for e in B])),
        ','
    ).alias('value_outofscope')
)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +---+-------------+----------------+
# |id |value_inscope|value_outofscope|
# +---+-------------+----------------+
# |A  |1,3          |2               |
# |B  |3            |4               |
# |C  |             |5,6             |
# +---+-------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to perform a *union* and a [symmetric] *difference* between two **sets**.

I've emboldened the word *sets* there because you will have to convert your `list` objects to `set` objects before you can perform the comparison.

Here's some code to illustrate against two scalar values:

```py
input_list = [1, 3]
comparison_list = [1, 2, 3]

values_in_scope = set(input_list) & set(comparison_list)
values_out_of_scope = set(input_list) ^ set(comparison_list)

print(f"values_in_scope: {values_in_scope}")
print(f"values_out_of_scope : {values_out_of_scope }")
```

This outputs:

```
values_in_scope: {1, 3}
values_out_of_scope : {2}
```

Additional note: the outputs have `{}` instead of `[]` as they are *set* objects. You can use the `list()` function to convert them back to a list should you wish e.g. `list(values_in_scope)`